# What are the uses of get() member from the shared_ptr class?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

My question is that what are the various ways in which get() member from the shared_ptr class can be used? And why can't we use **delete** to delete it?

Comment: You use `get()` when you need access to the managed raw pointer. And if you `delete sp.get();` you'll most likely, and deservedly, get undefined behavior

Comment: To use an API which requires raw pointers

Comment: This reminds me of many moons ago (before boost::shared_ptr) when I rolled my own refcounted pointer. I named the raw pointer accessor  'very_bad_public_method'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you had a function taking a raw pointer

```
void f(T *t); // non-owning pointer
```

And you had a smart pointer to a `T` object, you could pass it to that function by using `get()`

```
std::shared_ptr<T> sp{new T{}};  // or unique_ptr
//f(sp); // no good, type mismatch
f(sp.get()); // passes the raw pointer instead
```

APIs taking raw pointers are common, and still useful.  I'd suggest you watch [this part of Herb Sutter's talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xnqTKD8uD64#t=14m32s) from CppCon 2014, and probably the parts around it.

You should **not** attempt to delete this pointer, the smart pointer classes assume you will not do anything like that, and the smart pointer will still free the managed object in its own destructor when the time comes (after all, how would it know you deleted it?).

The smart pointer's job is to manage the object and delete it at the right time, if you want to manually manage the lifetime of the object (not usually recommended) then use a raw pointer.

If you do want to assume ownership of a `unique_ptr` you can do so by calling `release()`.

Comment: [boost also mentions](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#FAQ) that since you can use a custom deleter for shared pointers, it is not trivial to free the object via a raw pointer (even if it is uniquely owned).

Answer (score 4):

Usually you would use `get()` when you need to pass a raw pointer to an API that accepts such a pointer.

The `shared_ptr` class manages the ownership of the pointer, so it will automatically delete the owned memory when the lifetime of the smart pointer ends. If you try to delete the memory yourself then when the `shared_ptr` tries to deallocate you will wind up with undefined behavior.